# How to populate a select options collection in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

> **Summary**

I have a form using two drop downs. Once the first drop down selected value changed, the application makes an Ajax call to get the new list to display in the second drop down.

Think of it as a list of states/provinces filtered on the selected country.

The first drop down would be countryDropDown, and the second would be statesDropDown.

> **Code Sample**

**JSP**

```
<html:select name="countries"
             property="countryName"
             indexed="true"
             onchange="onCountryChange(this, 'states${index}')">
    <html:optionsCollection name="myViewModel" property="countries" />
</html:select>

<html:select styleId="states${index}"
             name="states"
             property="name"
             indexed="true">
    <html:optionsCollection name="myViewModel" property="states" />
</html:select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function onCountryChange(countriesDropDown, statesDropDownId) {
    var country = $(countriesDropDown).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: makeURL('/ent/refreshStates.do'),
        async: false,
        data: "country:" + country,
        success: function(states) {
            populate(statesDropDownId, states);
        },
        failure: function(e) {
            showAlert(e);
        }
    });
}

// In the following function, states is a list of ListValueBean.
function populate(statesDropDownId, states) {
    var statesDropDown = $(statesDropDownId);
    statesDropDown.empty();

    for(var i=0; i<states.length; i++) {
        statesDropDown.append("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value", states[i].value)
                      .text(states[i].label);
    }
}
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<select name="states[0].state" id="states0" data-size="10" style="display: none;">
    <option value="5052">MO</option>
    <option value="5051" selected="selected">CA</option>
    ...
</select>
<div class="btn-group boostrap-select">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="states0" title="5051">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">CA</span>
        "&nbsp;"
        <span class="caret">::before</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
            <li rel="0" class="selected">
                <a tabindex="0" class style>
                    <span class="text">CA</span>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems like the `select` is rendered but hidden by bootstrap and the control I see is changed for a button.

So even though the select gets populated, I can't get this wrapper button to update based on what's in the select it hides. :(

> **Current status**

The current behaviour is that the round trip to the server works just fine and everything is just as expected, except for the states which never gets updated in the drop down.

So how to make it work?

Comment: Well from a quick glance i'm not sure your id lookup for the statesDropDown will have '#' on the front of it, to make it a valid id selector.  You'd either want to put that in the string on the onchange invocation, or append it on the front in the populate method.

Comment: Can you create a exemple in jsfiddle so we can play with your code?

Comment: If you do `console.log(statesDropDown)` does it return the object that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you are not setting the attribute/text of new "option", those functions still referring to statesDropDown

```
statesDropDown.append("<option></option>")
                  .attr("value", states[i].value)
                  .text(states[i].label);
```

change it to this,

```
 var opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value", states[i].value).text(states[i].label);
 statesDropDown.append(opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the Bootstrap visual controls which aren't the actual data control, the information data contained in the Bootstrap controls need to be refreshed.

Furthermore, the control returned by the `$("#"+statesDropDownId)` doesn't actually return the expected control for some dark reasons unknown to me. The workaround I found that is working is as follows.

```
function assignStatesToDropDown(statesDropDownId, states) {
    var statesDropDown = $("#"+statesDropDownId)[0];
    statesDropDown.innerHTML = "";

    $.each(states, function(index, state) {
        var option="<option value='"+state>+"'>"+state+"</option>";
        var html=statesDropDown.innerHTML+option;
        statesDropDown.innerHTML=html;
    });

    refreshBootstrapDropDownsData();
}

function refreshBootstrapDropDownsData() {
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

And this works just fine.

Also, I only needed a list of string, so instead of returning a List, I did change the return type to a List and it behaved.